# Columns are missing while writing the output Json file in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

In pyspark, Facing the issue for columns missing in the data frame, while writing to the output json file in s3,
we have more than 30 columns in the data frame after performing the joins and unable to write those columns into output JSON file in the s3. is there any limit for columns to write in json format.

we have used the below command to write the output.

```
Finaldf.write.json('S3://bucket/output/filename.json')
```

Please help me with this

Thanks

Comment: are these columns nulls? try printing the data post join

Comment: Reproducible data, code or example is needed and this is nothing to do.

Comment: Is your JSON nested? Check df.printSchema, maybe columns are StructType